# Getting negative variance

Tags: variance, expected-value, density-function, estimators

I'm having a problem when calculating the variance of the following estimator:
$\hat\theta=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}D_n$ with $D_1....D_N$ independent random variables. 
In order to calculate the variance of this estimator, I follow the following procedure:
$\sigma_{\hat\theta}^{2}=E[(\hat\theta - E[\hat\theta])^2]=E[\hat\theta^2]+E[E[\hat\theta]^2]-2E[\hat\theta]E[E[\hat\theta]]$

Knowing that $f(D)=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{1}{\theta}D}$ and therefore, $E[D]= E[\hat\theta]=\theta$.

From this point, I get that $\sigma_{\hat\theta}^{2} = E[\hat\theta^2] +\theta^2-2\theta^2$

So, in order to obtain $E[\hat\theta^2] = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{m=1}^{N}E[D_nD_m]$ that will be $E[D^2]$ for $n=m$ and $E[D_n]E[D_m]=\theta^2$ for $n \neq m$. At this point, when calculating  $E[D^2]$ from its pdf I get that it is equal to 0, so I would obtain:

$E[\hat\theta^2] = \frac{1}{N^2}(N^2-N)\theta^2$ taking into account that there are $(N^2-N)$ values that satisfy the condition $n \neq m$  and therefore,

$\sigma_{\hat\theta}^{2} = \frac{1}{N^2}(N^2-N)\theta^2 +\theta^2-2\theta^2=-\frac{\theta^2}{N}$, which I know it is not ok since it is negative. Why could this be happening?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: SOLVED. The problem came from $E[D^2]$ which from my initial calculations obtained that it was 0, but it was not, being $E[D^2]=2\theta^2$. After this correction, the obtained variance is the one Deep North provided.

Comment: Warning bells should go off in your head that something is awry as soon as you calculate the expectation of $D^2$, _a nonnegative random variable_, as being $0$. -1 for wasting everybody's time.

Comment: The point is, you are asking for help in the wrong way by not even _thinking_ that your calculation of $E[D^2]$ might be incorrect and asking where you went wrong. Instead, you have a huge rigmarole about estimators etc and waste everyone's time by asking why the variance of your estimator is negative, Sheeesh! finding the variance of an exponential variance might even be an exercise in your textbook, and if not, your book probably has a table of commonly occurring with their means, variances, pdf formulas, etc neatly tabulated where you could have looked up the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $D$ just has an exponenital distribution $f(d)=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{1}{\theta}d}$ wtih $E(D)=\theta$ and  $Var(D)=\theta^2$.

Now your $\hat{\theta}$ is just the mean, by i.i.d

$Var(\hat\theta)=Var(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}D_n)=(\frac{1}{N})^2\theta^2+(\frac{1}{N})^2\theta^2+...+(\frac{1}{N})^2\theta^2$, totally there are $N$ such terms.

Therefore,the variance is $
\frac{1}{N}\theta^2$

Comment: But the variance of an estimator is defined as the expected value of the squared sampling deviations, so shouldn't I have to follow the formula $ E[(\hat\theta - E[\hat\theta])^2]$ to calculate it? @deep-north

Comment: You can, but your equaiton $E[\hat\theta^2] = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{m=1}^{N}E[D_nD_m]$ is not correct I think

Comment: You can, but your equaiton $E[\hat\theta^2] = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{m=1}^{N}E[D_nD_m]$ is not correct I think. You should do this way $E[\hat\theta^2]=E[(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}D_n)^2] =\frac{1}{N^2}E[(D_1+D_2+...+D_n)^2]=\frac{1}{N^2}E(D_1^2+D_2^2+...+D_n^2+2D_1D_2+...+2D_1D_n+2D_2D_3+...+D_2D_n+...+D_{n-1}D_n]$. It is a quite complicated way.

Comment: You are totally right. I had a mistake when calculating $E[D^2]$, which I already solved, and obtained the variance you mentioned with my method, so I guess now both are correct. Thanks a lot! @deep-north